# mod_deflate Supported Encodings for Compression

Tags: apache, compression, deflate, mod-deflate

It seems to me, that mod_deflate in Apache 2.2 will always return:

Content-Encoding: gzip

and never:

Content-Encoding: deflate

It was explained to me, that although there may be a deflate algorithm, mod_deflate is named after a file-format, in which the algorithm could be any of:

gzip, bzip. pkzip

Of those three, mod_deflate provides gzip.

It seems as though gzip is the most popular and widely-supported algorithm in web browsers, but I know some web servers and proxies do return Content-Encoding: deflate.

Aside from the confusion of the module's name, it true that mod_deflate will only return Content-Encoding: gzip?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact is mod_deflate supports [only deflate](http://www.vervestudios.co/projects/compression-tests/).

Comment: See his update on February 10, 2012, advising to read [this post](http://zoompf.com/blog/2012/02/lose-the-wait-http-compression).